# how can we find lat long from address in android?

Tags: android

i have a address and wants to find the latitude and longitude for that address...anybody know how can we get lat long from address in android...

i am using this code

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale
                    .getDefault());

            List<Address> address;

            address = coder.getFromLocationName(
                    "Pallekele International Cricket Stadium,Kandy, 1);
            if (address == null) {

            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

but i got this exception

```
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724): Service not Available
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:159)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at pack.sample.map.SampleMapApplication.onCreate(SampleMapApplication.java:38)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-02 17:46:56.086: ERROR/Exception(1724):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting service not available error. You need **an actual device**, not emulator. The [GeoCoder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) says:

> The Geocoder class requires a backend
>   service that is not included in the
>   core android framework. The Geocoder
>   query methods will return an empty
>   list if there no backend service in
>   the platform.

This [issue page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816#c6) says:

> Are you guys using this code on the Android 2.2 emulator? I'm also getting this error on the emulator but it works on the actual device (nexus one - android 2.2)
>
> Just installed CyanogenMod 6 alfa and now GeoCoder works fine. I guess it will work on final builds of stock Froyo too.

Comment: what is CyanogenMod 6 alfa?
should it install in my system?

Comment: it's now in release. i'm feeling lucky "CyanogenMod" :P